# (c cpp language)

Tags: c

please tell me about #define 
i want to execute c program when i wrote p in the place of printf
using #define but how please tell me...

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: There is no question posted that could be understood.

Comment: No questions ... no answers !!

Comment: #define is commonly used for variables such as matrix sizes port no etc... ( i think i understood ur Question )..next time be more specific

Comment: his english might not be that good, but he is asking about the #define directive here and how he can replace printf with the letter p.

Comment: @zedo he is not asking, he is telling. Questions have a question-mark. If you are unsure about this, ask about it here: http://english.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#define p printf

int main() {
        p("hello world");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This call doesn't work in TC++4.5 . But ran fine in codepad.org ( an online utility ).... Anyway , this definition will be useful

Comment: @vettipayyan if it didn't compile in TC++4.5, than that is not a compliant compiler. Oh wait, C++ has no compliance anyway, it's like a mix of spaghetti and macaroni.

Comment: @vettipayyan: Turbo C++ 4.5 was released back in 1993 with Windows 3.1. **What in the *world* are you doing using that? Get yourself a modern, standards-compliant compiler.** Try [Visual C++ 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP)—it's a free download.

Comment: @Cody Gray , actually i'm using MinGW in my lap . But this may be shocking to you : Most of the Indian colleges use Turbo C++ in labs as standard . And our students never get used to MS Visual Environment in labs !!!

Comment: @vettipayyan: That *is* interesting to me, and a bit shocking. I've been wondering why there have been so many people recently asking about Turbo C++ and archaic, proprietary Borland header files. But I couldn't figure out the appropriate forum to ask. I fully accept that someone might not want to wed themselves to Microsoft's offerings, instead opting for free and/or open-source solutions, but to be *teaching* a compiler that's nearly 20 years old under an operating system (MS-DOS) that you'll never program against in the real world just seems to be doing students an enormous disservice.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define P(X) printf("%d\n",X)
```

This only works for int tho. careful.